# Echo Outputs When Writing to File

Tags: batch-file, random, echo

When I use this code to select a character from my list, it works just fine but when I write it to a file using:

```
echo %pwd%>>pwd.gen
```

It will some times put the word "ECHO" randomly in the middle of the strings generated. Here is an example:

> jUrkunjcxC
>
> ecRECHOsI5w0T
>
> DmJfat13fT
>
> UWXOysW7Gb
>
> pPmS7138Ve
>
> nFkh32ECHOJd1

You can see it appears in line 2 and 6. This only happens about 20% of the time.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
title Password Generator
color f0
:firstRun
set /a cnt=0
cls
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p Len=What length should the password be?
set /a Len=%Len%-1
cls
set /p Amt=How many would you like to generate?
cls
goto start

:start
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, %Len%) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)

echo %pwd%>> pwd.gen

set /a cnt=%cnt%+1
if %cnt%==%Amt% goto end
goto start

:end
cls
echo Done!
echo Results have been saved to "pwd.gen"
echo.
choice /c YN /m "Restart?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto firstRun
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://superuser.com/a/349478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:start
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, %Len%) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)
```

- alfanum is 26+26+10 = 62 characters long.
- RANDOM gives a random number from 0-32,767
- When RANDOM is above 32240, `rnd_num` gets set to 62

  - string indexing starts at 0 not 1
  - the for `/F %%c` command indexes `alfanum:~62,1~` which is an empty string
  - it calls `echo` with no parameter, which prints `ECHO is on.` instead of returning a single character
  - `for /F` defaults to splitting strings with a space delimiter, which separates out the first word
  - `%%c` becomes `ECHO`
  - you add `ECHO` into the password.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation with your solution! The code works fine now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of a couple of things. While I'm not totally clear about the inner workings of the whole thing, I know what's causing it and how to fix it.

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` is 62 characters long. *However*, substrings in batch start with 0, so valid numbers go from 0 to 61. For whatever reason, an index-out-of-range combined with the `^` in `'echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%'` is causing the word `ECHO` to be displayed.

To get around this, simply don't add 1 when calculating rnd_num.

```
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768
```

Comment: The explanation of @TessellatingHeckler was very comprehensive but yours was much easier to understand! Thanks for your easy-fix!